# Creating alias- proper syntax

Tags: command-line, alias

Can anyone tell me if the following syntax is correct? I'm prepending my PATH variable then launching houdini

```
alias houdini_run='pathold=$PATH; PATH=/home/jim/yt-conda/bin:/home/jim/yt-conda/sbin; /opt/hfs16.5.595/bin/hindie-bin; PATH=$pathold'
```

The problem is when I run it, houdini DOES launch but I'm seeing a lot of missing package errors even though they definitely ARE installed in the bin directory defined in the above PATH.

ie

```
sh: 1: grep: not found 

sh: 1: awk: not found 

sh: 1: ls: not found
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? I can't get it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only have your specific paths in `$PATH` when running your desired program, then you can do it like this:

```
PATH=/path/to/bins /opt/my_program
```

In your case:

```
PATH=$HOME/yt-conda/bin:$HOME/yt-conda/sbin /opt/hfs16.5.595/bin/hindie-bin
```

And setting the alias would be like:

```
alias myprg="PATH=$HOME/yt-conda/bin:$HOME/yt-conda/sbin /opt/hfs16.5.595/bin/hindie-bin"
```

Now when you use `myprg` it sets `$PATH` to your desired paths then runs your program and leaves environment `$PATH` untouched when you're done using your program.

Answer (score 0):

`PATH` is used by the shell to find programs (`grep`, `awk`, `ls`) to execute.

By setting `PATH=/home/jim/yt-conda/bin:/home/jim/yt-conda/sbin` you're telling the shell to look ONLY in those directories.

Setting your `PATH` in an alias is unwise. You only need to do it once. Put something like

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/jim/yt-conda/bin:/home/jim/yt-conda/sbin
```

in your `~/.bashrc`